# Disable inheriting from base class in C++ in release mode

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, release, base-class

I would like to use abstract base classes for my classes. These abstract classes would serve the purpose of interfaces.. they are only there as a self-check to make sure that all necessary members are implemented. This speeds up the development. Since the error messages are much cleaner than the onces that will be produced from templates.

Since I'm going to use the implementing classes in templates, the base class itself would not be needed in a release build. In fact, it would only introduce overhead, even though it is small.

Is there some preprocessor magic that allows me to inherit from these abstract interfaces classes only if debug symbols are defined?

Comment: Using NDEBUG macro should do the trict: `class Derived\n #ifndef NDEBUG\n  : public AbstractBase\n#endif\n{ // body };`

Comment: The preprocessor is a text replacement tool, you can make it write any kind of program. That said, I wouldn't say that it's a good idea to use it for that. Also, before you start such hacks, profile your code to proof that it's really those ABCs that cause slowdown. Also, just to verify that a type has a function, use static assertions or somesuch, you don't need ABCs for that.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt: static assert sounds indeed like a cleaner way to do this :) thanks!

Comment: what you want is [C++ concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29). I suggest you give up on coding and come back in a few years when this is in C++, that's my plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide some of the messiness of macros with templates.

```
template <bool UseAbstractBase> class BaseT;

template <>
class BaseT<true> : public AbstractBase {};

template <>
class BaseT<false> {};

#ifndef USE_ABSTRACT_BASE
#define USE_ABSTRACT_BASE false
#endif

class Derived : BaseT<USE_ABSTRACT_BASE> {
    //...
};
```

Now, if you define `USE_ABSTRACT_BASE` to `true`, your derived objects will adopt the interface from `AbstractBase`. If you leave it undefined, your derived objects will not inherit the abstractions.